# jQuery ui tabs: executing code after selection event

Tags: jquery, select, user-interface, tabs

I am currently working on a web interface for a product using jQuery and jQuery ui. In our product, we have a tab-strip at the top. The very last tab is a "new tab" tab, and when the user clicks on it, it creates a new tab for the user (it works pretty much like tabbed browsing in most modern browsers). 
Currently, I am catching the selection event on the "new tab" tab, and in the callback function, I am doing all the work to create a new tab and display it. The initial problem that I encountered is that the new tab is not selected (even though I tell jQuery ui tabs to select it). What is happening is that jQuery ui tabs does select the new tab I've created. However, once my callback has finished executing, jQuery ui then goes ahead and reselects the "new tab" tab. In other words, the flow of execution is:

1. user clicks on "new tab" tab
2. some jQuery ui code executes
3. jQuery ui calls my callback function
4. my callback function creates a new tab
5. my callback function selects that new tab
6. jQuery ui executes some more code that applies the selection effects to "new tab" tab

I am currently working around this by placing my callback function within a setTimeout call. This works because it causes my callback function to get called after all the jQuery ui code executes.

My question is: is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do without setTimeout?

I feel that using setTimeout to control the flow of execution is hacky and will likely lead to problems down the road. I have looked for a after selected event, but to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
$tabs.tabs("option", "select", function(event, ui){
    if( ui.panel.id === tab_id_prefix + "plus-tab"){
        setTimeout( function(){
            tab_set_obj.newTab({}).setTabPage({
                page:       initial_page,
                context:    initial_context,
                title:      initial_title,
                select:     true
            });
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

EDIT: I can select the correct tab. The issue is one of timing. The way my code is currently structured requires that I select the tab I want after jQuery UI has done all of its work. I am currently doing that by using setTimeout, but was wondering if there was a better way.

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered just creating a new "new tab" and using the existing "new tab" that was just selected as the container for your new content? Its pretty easy to rename a tab. I think it would end up being cleaner and avoid having to fight the tabs control over which tab is getting selected.

Comment: Thanks Rob. That's a good suggestion. The reason that I want to do it in this manner is that new tabs can be created by more than just the "new tab" tab - so I would like to keep the tab creation logic all in one place. I will see if I can rework the code to both use your suggestion and keep all the creation logic clean and in one place

Comment: I have had a similar behaviour with jQueryUI tabs, and the problem was that, I had a callback in `select` event and I was getting the tab-length dynamically without storing previous value, i.e. `$('#tabs').tabs('length');`. When you programmatically select any tab, after its creation, you need select it, but code behind was calculating the tabs-length and selecting the last one, which in this case is your "new tab" tab. Just double check your code for that, debug the locals in your browser console. BTW, [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxt5J/1/) is an alternative to the same behaviour.

Comment: Might want to clarify that your asking for how to avoid selecting the tab in the settimeout, not how to select the correct tab.